# Navbar active link color change when I have empty href only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, navbar, bootstrap-5

I want to change active link color after click.
When I'm on START link I want have START writing in another color etc.
I have few links = "#" beacuse I haven't done it yet but my code works only in these cases, f.ex: when I click "O HODOWLI" then START is in another color as earlier, but "O HODOWLI" should be.
When I click "KOCIĘTA" then this writing is in another color as it should be. So when I have "#" it works but should in all cases.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
 $("ul.navbar-nav > li").click(function (e) {
 $("ul.navbar-nav > li").removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active");}) });
```

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light ">

<button class="navbar-toggler small-screen-navbar" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainmenu" aria-controls="mainmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Przełącznik nawigacji">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainmenu">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/start"> START </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/o_hodowli"> O HODOWLI </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> KOCIĘTA </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#"> NASZE KOTY </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/opieka"> OPIEKA NAD KOTAMI </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">OPINIE</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/kontakt"> KONTAKT </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav sm-icons">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/11891824050249/">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-square icon"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with plain js:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link')

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    links.forEach(link =>  link.classList.remove('active'))
    e.target.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light ">

<button class="navbar-toggler small-screen-navbar" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainmenu" aria-controls="mainmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Przełącznik nawigacji">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainmenu">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="/start"> START </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/o_hodowli"> O HODOWLI </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> KOCIĘTA </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#"> NASZE KOTY </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/opieka"> OPIEKA NAD KOTAMI </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">OPINIE</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/kontakt"> KONTAKT </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav sm-icons">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/11891824050249/">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-square icon"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```